# For loop with Sum() in summarise_by_time() mistakenly calculating zeros in numerator

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I want to create a summary for each variable of a given list of variables that are within dataframe `df`  but the problem is they keep procuding Num = 0 when they shouldn't. The outcome variables are numeric and all have 1s and 0s. I tried `!!outcome` and `outcome` in the `sum()` function in case it was read as a string rather than varable. I have tried two approaches with `summarize_by_time()`  and dplyr but no luck - both producing 0s. However, the code was working as expected when not in loop format....

```
# My data structure
df <- structure(list(Operation.Date = structure(c(1483401600, 1483401600, 
1483401600, 1483401600, 1483660800, 1483660800, 1483660800, 1483660800, 
1483660800, 1483401600, 1483747200, 1483574400, 1483574400, 1483488000, 
1483401600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    any_morbidity = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), any_ssi = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), any_uti = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

# First steps

# Set up a list of variables to summarize
outcomes_unadjusted <- c("any_morbidity", "any_ssi", "any_uti" )

# Set up a list to store the summary data frames
summaries <- list()
```

timetk approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(timetk)


# Use a for loop to iterate over the variables and apply summarize_by_time() to each
for (outcome in outcomes_unadjusted) {
  
  df_summary <- df %>%
    summarize_by_time(
      .date_var = Operation.Date,
      .by = "quarter", 
      # Summarize
      Num = sum(!!outcome),
       # Num = sum(!!outcome == 1, na.rm = TRUE),    # The only values are 1 and 0 . this didn't work either
      Denom = n(),
      Percent = (Num / Denom) * 100
    ) %>%
    mutate(mean = mean(Percent),
           outcome = paste0(outcome))
  
  # Add the summary data frame to the list
  summaries[[outcome]] <- df_summary
}


# Bind the summary data frames together
unadjusted_all <- bind_rows(summaries)

# Print the resulting data frame
print(unadjusted_all)
```

Using dplyr instead of timetk

```
# Other approach

library(zoo)


# group_by and summarise() - doesn't work
for (outcome in outcomes_unadjusted) {
  df_summary <- df %>%
  mutate(quarter = as.yearqtr(as.Date(Operation.Date))
         ) %>%  # Extract the quarter from the Operation.Date column
  group_by(quarter) %>%  # Group the data by quarter
    summarize(
      Num = sum(outcome == 1),      
      Denom = n(),
      Percent = (Num / Denom) * 100
    ) %>%
    mutate(mean = mean(Percent),
           outcome = paste0(outcome))
  
  # Add the summary data frame to the list
  summaries[[outcome]] <- df_summary
}


# Bind the summary data frames together
unadjusted_all <- bind_rows(summaries)

# Print the resulting data frame
print(unadjusted_all)
```

Comment: I should think the first thing anyone would want to see would be str(df) results.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding `!!sym()` around the outcome variable to unquote it.

`sum(!!sym(outcome) , na.rm = TRUE)`